# Analysis of concentrations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, analysis

I process images of trace gases concentrations distribution over the layer of atmosphere.

I need to analyse values of concentrations, rather detect so-called "background" values and "extremal" ones automatically in ArcMap.

At the moment I carry out such procedure manually: I classify them each image, analyse myself ranges and determine the one with critical values. After that I use Raster Calculator to exclude values which are different with normal (background) ones. But such the approach is subjective and there is the probability of some mistake from my side.

Is there some tool in ArcMap which is able to analyse values or a raster and distinguish background values and areas of extremal concentrations?

The sample of my image is attached.

[image]

Comment: What are your manual steps?

Comment: I classify them each image, analyse myself ranges and determine the one with critical values. After that I use Raster Calculator to exclude values which are different with normal (background) ones. But such the approach is subjective and there is the probability of some mistake from my side.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with these and any other requested clarifications, or other improvements.